# Simplifying an ajax script in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and I'm working on a page that has several tabs that all have multiple carousels in them (each with a ton of images) I've managed to write an AJAX script that pulls the images from a JSON file I've created (for one of the carousels). I'm planning on making similar JSON file for the rest, but what I'm wondering though is there a way to write the AJAX script so that it grabs the id from the HTML so I don't have to make a unique AJX script for each version of the carousel

Here's how my HTML looks for the carousel:

```
    <div id="ShaluCarousel1b" class="carousel slide"><!-- class of slide for animation -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel1b">

        </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
    </div>
```

And here's my AJAX script:

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert("An AJAX error occured: " +status + "\nError: " +error);
            }
        });
    $.ajax({
        url:'json/carousel1b',
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
            console.log('grabbing photos');

            var totalPictures = data['totalPictures'];
            for (var i=0; i<totalPictures; i++) {
                console.log("new image");

                if(i<1){
                    console.log("first image");

                    var d = "<div class='item active'>";
                    d += "<a href='" +data.pictures[i]['photo'] +"' rel='prettyPhoto'>";
                    d += "<img src='" +data.pictures[i]['photo'] +"' >";
                    d += "</a>";
                    d += "</div>";

                $('#carousel1b').append(d);
                }

                else {
                    console.log("image" +i);

                var d = "<div class='item'>";
                    d += "<a href='" +data.pictures[i]['photo'] +"' rel='prettyPhoto'>";
                    d += "<img src='" +data.pictures[i]['photo'] +"' alt=''>";
                    d += "</a>";
                    d += "</div>";

                $('#carousel1b').append(d);

                $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
                    console.log('pp init');


                }
            }   
        }
    })
</script>
```

I'm basically wondering if there is a way to pull the id (carousel1b) from the HTML and inject it into the AJAX strip in the "url:'jason/**carousel1b** and the "$('**carousel**').append(d)"

Comment: Belongs on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks to diodeus for directing me to codereview - if anyone is interested though I did get an answer: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29150/simplifying-an-ajax-script-in-my-html